# How do I initialize a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization, declaration

I got a comment on how I initialize my struct in C, saying that It does not work and it does not compile either.

This is how I create and initialize a structure in C.

```
struct {
int a; 
int b;
char arr[3];
.
.
.
} data = {
.a = 1, 
.b = 2
};

main(){
/* do stuff */
}
```

This how I initialize my struct and It works and compiles. Yet I got a comment saying this would compile for c++ but not for C.  Can someone ensure me that this correct alternative? If not why is it compiling with no errors?

Comment: `char [3]arr;` is neither C nor C++. Please post real code, even better post a [mcve]

Comment: And what is `.arr = {}` supposed to do? Hint: it's wrong

Comment: Yes I know. But it's not about these stuff you mentioned above. The  question itself, is wether it is ok or not to create the struct and initializing it directly after, just I showed above.

Comment: You edited out the critical C vs C++ syntax difference.

Comment: @moab when you post examples, they should be consistent with the question, otherwise is causes confusion. Read this: [ask].

Comment: Yes, you can initialize a structure immediately after defining it in C.  However, the syntax of the initializer must be valid C.  In the original version of the question, the notation used `.arr = {}` to initialize the array.  The empty braces notation is valid in C++ and not valid in standard C.  And, conversely, the designated initializer notation is valid in C and not valid in C++ yet.  So that part of the initializer was not strictly comparable in either standard C or standard C++.

Comment: Well Yes. I didn't take care of  the typo and intializing errors. But my question was about if it is valid to initialize a structure immediately after defining it in C. And yes, I edited the original code, since I was a little careless  when writing it and your comments was about the code itself and not if I am able to do structure my code as above or not. However I got my question answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the declaration of the data member `arr`. Instead of

```
char [3]arr;
```

you have to write

```
char arr[3];
```

You may not initialize an array with empty braces. So write for example

```
struct {
int a; 
char arr[3];
.
.
.
} data = {
.a = 1, 
.arr = { 0 }
};
```

In fact it is enough to write

```
struct {
int a; 
char arr[3];
.
.
.
} data = {
.a = 1
};
```

The array implicitly will be initialized with zeroes.

Comment: Thanks, this ensures that I'm able to create and initialize a struct just I did above, beside the typos I did :)